# Input type='image' as submit button behaves differently than 'submit'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have multiple buttons submitting a form. I check to see which button was clicked by the input value that gets passed into my controller.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(MyModel model, string command)
```

The html below works. In my controller `command` equals `myValue`

```
<input type="submit" name="command" value="myValue" />
```

The html below doesn't work. In my controller `command` is `null`

```
<input type="image" name="command" src="..." value="myValue"/>
```

[W3C says the type 'image' is a submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#image-button-state-%28type=image%29)

So why are these two input elements behaving differently?

Comment: Afaik `value` does not work for image submit buttons, at least in FF. Sadly W3C is not the same as reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image submit button indeed behaves differently, *by definition*, both according to the expired working draft linked to in the question and the current HTML5 CR draft and the HTML 4.01 recommendation. According to HTML5 CR, [construction of the form data set](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set) does not add a name=value pair for an image submit button but name.x=... and name.y=... with the coordinates of the clicked location as values. This corresponds to old definitions and browser practice, except that Chrome *additionally* adds a name=value pair.

Thus, in your case, the form data will contain the fields `command.x` and `command.y`, with values that you are probably not interested in. This is what you need to take as starting point when coding the form handler. This means that if you need to recognize which of several image buttons was used, you need to give them different `name` attributes.

Comment: Great in depth explanation. The sentence that explains this is in part 3.3 of your link

Comment: Sorry but... This doesn't seems to provide any working answer, it does not include working code. It explain why OP code doesn't work and the SUBTLE solution you provided, unfortunately, does not work for me. Or were you trying to say that it's impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one hidden field and set the command name in that hidden field which ever button is click and get the name of the button that submited the form on server side.

**Javascript**

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    var commandName = $(this).attr("val");
    $("input[type=hidden]").val(commandName);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="command">

    <input type="submit" value="submitbtn" class="submit" />
    <input type="image" src="..." value="imagebtn" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This unnecessarily relies on client-side scripting as regards to essential functionality. With scripting disabled, the page would silently fail to work the intended way.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Asp.net webform application internally uses the same technique i have mentioned above. check the html of asp.net web form application you will find __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and maybe not safe) way to accomplish this task is with inline JQuery, here's how :

**VIEW :**

```
<input type="image" src="..." onclick="$('#hidImgValue').val('Image1');" />

<input type="hidden" id="hidImgValue" name="command" value="none" />
```

**CONTROLLER :**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(MyModel model, string command)
```

Command var will have `"Image1"` as value.